# How do I list all of my addresses in namecoind?

Tags: wallet, address, namecoin

I just created a new address using `namecoind getnewaddress` and am trying to figure out what command lists them (in case I forget mine).

What is the command to list my addresses (that I have a private key for)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namecoind listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
```

`0` means to include even transactions with no confirmations, `true` means to show even "empty" addresses